# Ninject and F#?

Tags: f#, ninject

Has anyone used Ninject in F# code? any hint is appreciated.

Comment: what concrete issues have you found?

Comment: I haven't faced any issues. Actually I just want to use Ninject in F# but I can't find any sample code/project. Do you have any that you can share? A simple working example will do

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there's anything particular about using Ninject in F#. The Ninject example of Samurai / IWeapon / Sword looks like this:

```
open Ninject

type IWeapon =
    abstract Hit: string -> unit

type Sword() =
    interface IWeapon with
        member x.Hit s = printfn "Slash %s" s    

type Samurai(weapon: IWeapon) =
    member x.Attack target =
        weapon.Hit target

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    use kernel = new StandardKernel()
    kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>() |> ignore
    kernel.Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf() |> ignore
    let samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>()
    samurai.Attack "enemy"
    0
```

F# features like implicit constructors and type inference make the code quite concise.

Comment: Thanks for this as well...was searching and found this as an exact answer to my question.